# C# LINQ Lamda for outer join

Tags: c#, linq

The scenario:

I have a list of Language keywords for two languages: Language A and Language B.
I want to create a left outer join that joins the two lists the on property: "Reference",
i.e. I want a list of all "LanguageKeywords" in Language A and if the keyword exists in LanguageB, populate its "LanguageB" property value respectively...

```
public class LanguageKeyword
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string LanguageA { get; set; }
    public string LanguageB { get; set; }
}
```

Attempt:

```
var langA = new List<LanguageKeyword2>();
var langB = new List<LanguageKeyword2>();

var fullList = langA.GroupJoin(langB, a => a.Reference, b => b.Reference, (a, b) =>
    new LanguageKeyword2()
    {
        Reference = a.Reference,
        LanguageA = a.LanguageA,
        LanguageB = ???
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: @AccessDenied - No, I have asked for Lamda syntax whereas other question did not.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you do the same as in the following answer of specified thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/21584913/1099716

Comment: @AccessDenied - Kind of, I have managed to do it with similar Selects/Manys, it's just such overkill, I will check the other answers on that thread though and hopefully come up with something clean and readable, thanks!